# Tooltip no Angular

Tags: angular, tooltip

Alguém ai sabe como inserir tolltip no angular ? Já tentei de diversas maneiras e não foi...

Tentei usando o MatTooltipModule instalando via comando: ng add @angular/material

Tentei usando CDN colocando os links CDN do bootstrap tanto o CSS, quanto do Jquery e não funcionou.

Comment: É necessário fornecer mais informações do seu problema. Um exemplo de código, assim como a versão do angular que você esta trabalhando, a versão do angular material que esta usando e etc. Para que possamos ajudar.
Para mais informações de como construir uma perguta 
 use [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Opa cara, desculpa a demora na resposta rsrsrs... Mas eu consegui resolver o problema, era só baixar o bootstrap via npm e colocar os caminhos no angular.json assim só colocando o jquery no arquivo typescript do component alvo e colocar os código html de tooltip...

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro:

`ng add @angular/material`

Importe no APP Module

```
import: [
...
    MatTooltipModule
...
]
```

e use no HTML

```
<button matTooltip="Estou aqui"></button>
```